# Wordpress Category page (archive.php) == 404 (Not found)

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, categories, permalinks, taxonomy

I am trying to set permalinks as:

```
domain.com/category_name
domain.com/postname
```

And I can't find a way to make this work.
On screenshot down below you have my settings of permalinks, thats the set-up I want, but I am getting an 404 on category pages.

I tried to reset clear htaccess and flushed permalinks to recreate it. (its writable)
I tried to put "." as category base.

Nothing helps.
If I set in settings custom structure : `/%category%/%postname%/`, and I set category base to ".". That works, but I get post pages under category and I dont want my post page URL to have a category in it.

Anything is helpful! :) Thank you

[image: Permalink settings in Wordpress]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found some solution if someone needs it in future:

I left my settings in permalink as

Custom structure: `/%category%/%postname%/`
Category base: `.`

And I installed plugin: "Permalink Manager Lite" and used it to manually remove category from the URL of each posts.